# Ehcache shutdown causing an exception while running test suite

Tags: spring, junit4, ehcache, spring-test

I'm experiencing the following problem.

I have a test suit in my project and each individual test runs fine.

However when I run them as a suite I some of them fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The dao Cache is not alive (STATUS_SHUTDOWN)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache$CacheStatus.checkAlive(Cache.java:4269)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.checkStatus(Cache.java:2703)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1576)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCache.get(EhCacheCache.java:61)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.inspectCacheables(CacheAspectSupport.java:310)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:198)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
```

Is there a way to avoid this behavior, i.e. keep the cache alive across multiple test or shutting it down properly?

Comment: How it's possible to set shared property to false in testing context, it's possible to provide an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to set shared property to false in `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` or `EhCacheCacheManager` in the testing context.

Comment: But it's also possible with that configuration?
 
`<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider"/>  <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />`

Comment: How it's possible to set shared property to false in testing context, is it possible to provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

Make a seperate cache config for tests only! and put scope "prototype"

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class EhCacheConfig {

 @Bean(name = "cacheManager")
 @Scope("prototype")
 public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
    return new EhCacheCacheManager(getEhCacheFactory().getObject());
 }

 @Bean
 @Scope("prototype")
 public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean getEhCacheFactory() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
    factoryBean.setShared(true);
    return factoryBean;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your failing test class with `@AutoConfigureCache`.
By default, this annotation will install a `NoOpCacheManager`, i.e.
a basic, no operation `CacheManager` implementation suitable for disabling caching, typically used for backing cache declarations without an actual backing store.
It will simply accept any items into the cache not actually storing them.

[Spring Documentation on @AutoConfigureCache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/core/AutoConfigureCache.html)

[Spring Documentation on @NoOpCacheManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/NoOpCacheManager.html?is-external=true)

Comment: it is possible for spring boot app only.

Comment: yes it works for witn Spring boot tests, thanks

Answer (score 0):

JUnit share Spring context for speed.
I've avoid from this exception when remove explicitly Spring context closing in one of my test. See [Reuse spring application context across junit test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501975/reuse-spring-application-context-across-junit-test-classes)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs basically, Whenever you Cache shared among multiple applications. **So try not to share your cache by setting shared property to false.**

`<spring:bean id="ehcache"    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">   <spring:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />    <spring:property name="shared" value="false" /> </spring:bean>`

But on execution you will encounter

**Another CacheManager with same name 'cacheManager' already exists in the same VM. IllegalStateException**

To counter this we need to mention

`<spring:property name="cacheManagerName" value="abc" />`

I hope finally issue will be resolved.

Comment: Adding the name does not remove the 'cacheManager' already exists in the same VM. IllegalStateException exception