# Cache is closed causing an exception while running test suite

Tags: ehcache, spring-test, jcache, shared-cache

I'm experiencing a problem similar to the described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16281802/1429387).

I have a test suite that runs fine in development environment. One of the tests fails when executed in Bitbucket Pipelines with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cache[model.Role] is closed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache[model.Role] is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:364)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
   ....
```

I want to try the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16370326/1429387) but I don't know how to apply it to my project. The [second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45030054/1429387) depends on ehcache.xml file. I don't have this file, everything is configured in JavaConfig. How can I adopt the proposed solutions for **EhCache + JCache** (JSR-107) in JavaConfig?

My cache configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    private final javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Object, Object> jcacheConfiguration =
            Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(CacheConfigurationBuilder
                    .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class,
                            ResourcePoolsBuilder.newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                    .heap(100, EntryUnit.ENTRIES))
                    .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(60)))
                    .build());

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer cacheManagerCustomizer() {
        return cm -> {
            createIfNotExists(cm, "model.Role");
            createIfNotExists(cm, "model.User.roles");
            // ...
        };
    }

    private void createIfNotExists(CacheManager cacheManager, String cacheName) {
        if (cacheManager.getCache(cacheName) == null) {
            cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, jcacheConfiguration);
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation group: 'javax.cache', name: 'cache-api'
implementation group: 'org.ehcache', name: 'ehcache'
implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-jcache'
```

The failing test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SecondLevelCacheTest {
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private CacheManager manager;

    @Before
    public void initCacheManager() {
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        manager = provider.getCacheManager();

        final String cacheRegion = "model.Role";
        manager.getCache(cacheRegion).clear();
    }

    @Test
    public final void givenEntityIsLoaded_thenItIsCached() {
        final String cacheRegion = "model.Role";

        boolean hasNext = manager.getCache(cacheRegion).iterator().hasNext();
        final Role role = roleRepository.findByName("USER");
        boolean hasNext2 = manager.getCache(cacheRegion).iterator().hasNext();
        final Role role2 = roleRepository.findByName("USER");

        Assert.assertFalse(hasNext);
        Assert.assertTrue(hasNext2);
    }
}
```

The most upvoted solution is "to set shared property to false in the testing context." How can I do this with regard to my configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Annotate your failing test class with `@AutoConfigureCache`. By default, this annotation will install a `NoOpCacheManager`, i.e. a basic, no operation `CacheManager` implementation suitable for disabling caching, typically used for backing cache declarations without an actual backing store. It will simply accept any items into the cache not actually storing them.

[Spring Documentation on @AutoConfigureCache](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/core/AutoConfigureCache.html)

[Spring Documentation on @NoOpCacheManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/NoOpCacheManager.html?is-external=true)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to provide a custom `CachingProvider` that does not share `CacheManager`-s. An example solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044095/1774076).

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution you are talking about is based on Ehcache 2. You are using Ehcache 3 (good for you), so it's not valid.

Spring will take care of closing the `CacheManager` so normally, you don't need to take care of anything. Also, you do not need to access it through the `CachingProvider`. You can `@Autowired` the `javax.cache.CacheManager` and that way you are sure to get the right one.

However, you are using Hibernate. You should make sure that Spring and Hibernate are using the same `CacheManager`. The way to configure it depends on the Spring and Hibernate version.

Can we have the full stack trace? Right now it feels like something is closing the `CacheManager` without deregister it from the `CachingProvider`. This is impossible unless you are closing the `org.ehcache.CacheManager`without closing the `javax.cache.CacheManager` wrapping it. Closing the later will cause the deregistration.

Comment: Hello.
Sorry for posting in old question, I am facing the same error here for jhipster application (Spring boot 2.7 + ehcache 3.10.0)
I tried all suggestions above but none of them did work.

Any idea please ?