# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache[default-update-timestamps-region] is closed"

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

Running JUnit tests in Eclipse STS for a Spring Boot 2.5 application with Spring Data JPA occasionally triggers the trace below at the end the tests. Running the same tests from the command line via Maven does not seem to trigger this behavior.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache[default-update-timestamps-region] is closed
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache.checkClosed(Eh107Cache.java:528) ~[ehcache-3.9.7.jar:3.9.7]
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache.put(Eh107Cache.java:173) ~[ehcache-3.9.7.jar:3.9.7]
    at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheAccessImpl.putIntoCache(JCacheAccessImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-jcache-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.DirectAccessRegionTemplate.putIntoCache(DirectAccessRegionTemplate.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.TimestampsCacheEnabledImpl.invalidate(TimestampsCacheEnabledImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$AfterTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:995) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:513) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$400(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:305) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:589) ~[spring-orm-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:835) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:809) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:672) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... <app-specific-frames>
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.publishEvent(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:413) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.afterSessionEnded(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:648) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.clearSession(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:530) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:399) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:78) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:145) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.fireEndpointOnClose(WsSession.java:759) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:708) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.doClose(WsSession.java:666) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.close(WsSession.java:653) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.closeInternal(StandardWebSocketSession.java:235) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.close(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:142) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketSessionDecorator.close(WebSocketSessionDecorator.java:160) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.close(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:271) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.stop(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:288) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.stop(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:301) ~[spring-websocket-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:234) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1067) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:172) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.closeAndWait(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:137) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationShutdownHook.run(SpringApplicationShutdownHook.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache[default-update-timestamps-region] is closed
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache.checkClosed(Eh107Cache.java:528) ~[ehcache-3.9.7.jar:3.9.7]
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107Cache.put(Eh107Cache.java:173) ~[ehcache-3.9.7.jar:3.9.7]
    at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheAccessImpl.putIntoCache(JCacheAccessImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-jcache-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.DirectAccessRegionTemplate.putIntoCache(DirectAccessRegionTemplate.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.TimestampsCacheEnabledImpl.preInvalidate(TimestampsCacheEnabledImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.invalidateSpaces(ActionQueue.java:666) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.registerCleanupActions(ActionQueue.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:389) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:377) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1438) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1701) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1683) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:239) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

NOTE: This trace is similar to [this question with a different exception type, different version of dependencies, and different stack trace origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544644/hibernate-second-level-cache-is-closed-while-running-a-couple-of-spring-tests) but the answers to that question do not solve this.

Comment: any update on your problem please ?

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this with the latest versions of Spring 2.7+ and Eclipse. I never found the root cause, unfortunately.