# Speeding up Spring unit tests

Tags: spring, junit

I have JUnit 4 test classes that all inherit from a common class. This parent class provide services such as minimal tests setup and DB management.

But this parent class is long to execute mainly because my Spring context loading is slow.

Is there any way to execute the code from the parent class only once for all the tests classes that inherit from it?

Comment: How are you loading the application context? If you use the correct annotations Spring will cache the loading of your application context.

Comment: Please show some code, your base class.

Comment: Thanks men, but mavarazy pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: This question was good and well-formed, and brough a useful answer. It should be re-opened. Even general questions make sense, and I thinkg that was one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at similar question for reference:

[Reuse spring application context across junit test classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501975/reuse-spring-application-context-across-junit-test-classes)

This works good with batch of tests. I personally use single configuration for all tests in one module, with small downside, which is that even if test requires only part of the context, it is still better to load whole context, so it might take more time for individual test to execute, but test run faster at batches.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! The difficulty has been to retrieve the application context in order to bootstrap my test WicketApplication, but once done, it is has been a piece of cake!