# Running selenium unit tests with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I have some integration tests that use Selenium and the HtmlUnitDriver to verify my web app behaves correctly from the browser. In IntelliJ, I'm able to run `./gradlew bootRun` to start my embedded web server, and then run my Selenium tests manually.

The tests run as expected.

However, I'm wondering what the best strategy is to run these in an automated fashion on my CI Server (TeamCity in this case). Simply running `bootRun` doesn't quite work since the task runs until it gets terminated.

Should I create a script that runs bootRun, and then I can terminate gradle somehow after the tests complete? I'd also like to use my `application.properties` file I have in `src/test/resources` instead of `src/main/resources` which `bootRun` uses normally.

Comment: Have you considered going through [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications) and also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591160/use-one-spring-boot-context-through-all-springboottests) stackover post ?

Comment: What you've posted is for running regular unit tests in a spring context. I am attempting to use selenium to run my full web application and test it via the browser.