# How to run parallel integration tests in gradle in separate process

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

I have to run Spring boot integration tests in parallel to reduce the time as they took quite a few minutes right now.
When I use `maxParallelForks` they run in parallel but the issue is since they are Spring boot tests they are setting up the context and due to memory sharing they are failing?
I have tried to search online a lot but still unsuccessful to run them in parallel in a separate process, or in a way that they do not share the memory anymore.

Is there any way to do that and yes what would be the best approach to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501975/reuse-spring-application-context-across-junit-test-classes

Comment: I am actually searching for running test classes in a separate jvm process so that they do not share the memory. This link suggests to reuse..

Comment: Don't you think its too heavy on resources to do that ?

Comment: Yes, I agree, but atleast I wanna try so that I can atleast reduce build time on local else I have to wait more than 5 minutes to verify everything is fine on local before pushing every commit in CI CD environment.

Comment: Could you perhaps  provide a [mcve]?