# Reuse Spring application context across different Spock tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, spock

I would like to reuse the same Spring context across several integration tests written in Spock framework.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) context caching is based on `classes` property of `@ContextConfiguration` annotation.

That's an example test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
class ExampleIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    def 'should reuse Spring context if already created'() {
        expect:
        1 == 1
    }
}
```

The second test also contains the same `@ContextConfiguration` annotation, i.e.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

but when I run all tests I can see in the console that Spring context is created per each test. I would like to cache it between different tests.
Am I missing something? Basically, I would like to achieve the same thing as described here [(stackoverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501975/reuse-spring-application-context-across-junit-test-classes/) but in Spock instead of JUnit.

Answer (score 2):

Context Caching is done by the Spring Framework, it follows the rules described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching), i.e., it builds a context cache key factoring in different factors. As long as all of them are the same, it reuses the same context.

- locations (from @ContextConfiguration)
- classes (from @ContextConfiguration)
- contextInitializerClasses (from @ContextConfiguration)
- contextCustomizers (from ContextCustomizerFactory)
- contextLoader (from @ContextConfiguration)
- parent (from @ContextHierarchy)
- activeProfiles (from @ActiveProfiles)
- propertySourceLocations (from @TestPropertySource)
- propertySourceProperties (from @TestPropertySource)
- resourceBasePath (from @WebAppConfiguration)

Spock supports `@SpringBootTest` or any of the other Spring Boot test annotations, such as `@WebMvcTest`, directly and you should not add an explicit `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Finally it turned out that tests were running with different profiles and that's why Spring did not reuse the context.

Comment: k13i good that you found out the difference, could you please accept the answer.

Comment: My tests are not sharing a context even though they share a common base class annotated with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = [MyTestConfig, MyApp])`. The annotations listed above are not used at all. How can I troubleshoot the context caching?

Comment: You can see what is going on, by setting the logger `org.springframework.test.context.cache` to `DEBUG`. If you are using `@MockBean` then this will also prevent reuse.